# Gender Specific Translations

Tags: django, translation

## Task

I have a extended UserModel, which includes the users gender:

```py
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    gender = models.CharField(
        _('Gender'),
        max_length=1,
        choices=(
            ('f', _('Female')),
            ('m', _('Male')),
        ),
        default='m'
    )
    ...
```

I would like to display a gender specific translations in my template:

> Please contact **him**.

or

> Please contact **her**.

## Questions ?

- How would you handle the task?
- Is there a better solution, than my current (see: Answers)?

  - maybe something equal as pluralization is handled

Comment: Gender isn't binary. What about folks who don't identify as male or female? Something to consider in the up-front design; perhaps just let people select their pronoun set instead of asking for a gender?

Comment: @FlipperPA For sure your right. Any developer should keep this in mind. Actually I use more genders in my project. I just removed them here, to simplify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I use [contextual markers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers) to create separate translations:

```
{% if user.member.gender == 'm' %}
    {% blocktrans context "male" %}Please contact him.{% endblocktrans %}
{% else %}
     {% blocktrans context "female" %}Please contact her.{% endblocktrans %}
{% endif %}
```